# Error with R tibble: Error in vectbl_restore(xo, x) : object 'tibble_restore_impl' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tibble, rstan

I've had this error pop up out of nowhere and I have no idea what to do to fix it. Running the code below,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

del <- tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(2, 4))
ggplot(data = del) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

results in the following error:

```
Error in vectbl_restore(xo, x) : object 'tibble_restore_impl' not found
```

However, if I instead do the following, it works fine:

```
del <- tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(2, 4))
ggplot(data = as.data.frame(del)) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

And it is not specific to ggplot or tibble creation. If for example I import a .csv file (using read.csv), and the select/filter a subset using dplyr, I then get the same error if I try to plot it using ggplot2, or if I try to save it using write.table(). I had none of these issues until last Monday and I'm not sure what caused it. I haven't updated any of the aforementioned packages. The only thing I've tried to do is install cmdstanr, which I didn't manage to do since I was getting the following error:

```
> library(cmdstanr)
> check_cmdstan_toolchain()
Error: 
A toolchain was not found. Please install RTools 3.5 and run

write('RTOOLS35_HOME=rtools35/install/path/', file = "~/.Renviron", append = TRUE)
replacing 'rtools35/install/path/' with the actual install path of RTools 3.5.

Then restart R and run 'cmdstanr::check_cmdstan_toolchain(fix = TRUE)'.
```

I stopped trying to install it because I thought it wasn't worth my time since I already have a functioning version of rstan.

Comment: Please check your package version.  It is working fine

Comment: akrun, thanks for the reply. What do you mean by "check your package version"? I'm using tibble_3.1.5 and ggplot2_3.3.2, which are a bit out of date, but I don't see why it should stop working unless. Should I try updating them?

Comment: I am using `R 4.1.1` with `ggplot2_3.3.5` and the `tibble_3.1.4`. Maybe it is your updated tibble version causing issue.  Not sure though because our package versions are different for both the packages